# C# operator overloading for matrix

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I have written a code for operator overloading for matrix as below. But the result for multiplication with a negative sign doesn't work well.

```
 public static MyMatrix operator -(MyMatrix A, MyMatrix B)
{
    MyMath math = new MyMath();
    return math.matSubtract(A, B);
}

public static MyMatrix operator -(MyMatrix A, float B)
{
    MyMathmath = new MyMath();
    return math.matSubtract(A, B);
}

public static MyMatrix operator -(MyMatrix A)
{
    MyMathmath = new MyMath();
    return math.matMul(A, -1);
}

public static MyMatrix operator *(MyMatrix , MyMatrix B)
{
    MyMath = new MyMath();
    return math.matMul(A, B);
}
```

I have checked math.matmul and subtract working fine.

Then, I run tests like this:

```
var A = new MyMatrix(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
print(A);
var B = new MyMatrix(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
print(B) ;
```

```
A = [0 1 2 
     3 4 5 
     6 7 8]
```

B = [0 1 2 
     3 4 5 
     6 7 8]

```
print(A*-B)
print(-B*A)
print(A*-B*-B);
print(A*(-B)*(-B));
var C = -B;
print(A*C*C)
```

ans = [-15   -18   -21
       -42   -54   -66
       -69   -90  -111]

ans = [15   18   21
       42   54   66
       69   90  111]

ans= [-180         -234         -288
      -558         -720         -882
      -936        -1206        -1476]


ans= [-180         -234         -288
      -558         -720         -882
      -936        -1206        -1476]


ans= [180         234         288
      558         720         882
      936        1206        1476]

Could it be the precedence issue or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting! Does the same thing happen if you just multiply it once by -B?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was aliasing: I was updating the object value.